# aiohttp - Fatal read error on socket transport - TimeoutError

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, aiohttp

We use aiohttp with Python3.5 to post data into elastic search. The post line is as follows:

```
response = await self._http_session.request(method, url,
                    data = data_fun(), params = params)
```

Usually everything runs just fine but from time to time, following error occurs:

```
Fatal read error on socket transport
protocol: <aiohttp.parsers.StreamProtocol object at 0x7fde5eb7eeb8>
transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=21 read=polling write=<polling, bufsize=261832>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 664, in _read_ready
   data = self._sock.recv(self.max_size)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

It would be fine, if it would just raise exception and continue to function normally. In our case it seems though, that this error causes entire asyncio task, in which the post request is executed, to freeze.

We tracked down the error raise to https://github.com/python/asyncio/blob/master/asyncio/selector_events.py#L674 which subsequently calls the `call_exception_handler`.

Is it possible that this exception renders the `_https_session` invalid/unusable and we need to create new one? Or is there anything else we can do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TimeoutError` should close one connection from `ClientSession`. Session itself continues to work.

Perhaps you should catch exception in your code too.

Sorry, cannot write more without looking on the source code.

P.S.
Why you don't use `async with` statement for controlling response lifetime?

Like

```
async with self._http_session.request(method, url,
        data = data_fun(), params = params) as response:
    ...
```

Comment: Yeah, async with should be used in this case, will change that. The full code can be found here - https://repl.it/CjAB . And the error is actually caught by our except clause which should be just fine..

Comment: BTW are you aware about aioes existence?